# Scraping other people's ratings from IMDb/avoiding the pagination keys in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, pagination, imdb

Since IMDb removed the ability to export other people's ratings I have been trying to find a way to scrape them but I am a programming noob. I have followed this Youtube tutorial which scrapes general IMDb data with R: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28pyEDV9mMw&t=0s. I managed to adapt it to scrape a ratings link but it can only retrieve the first page of information as the ratings pages use a pagination key in the URL which completely changes with each page so I can't use seq() function to loop it. Is there a way to instead use the 'next' button to loop it instead of a URL pattern? Is there a way to extract and apply the pagination keys to a loop?

As an example here's what two page URLs look like:

```
https://www.imdb.com/user/ur3954564/ratings?sort=date_added%2Cdesc&mode=detail&paginationKey=mfq5ijak6z7uymjwuuwsomnsegl34knnqsdztp6xeepepyyfxdfiwpol52uhtjimq3iwclnm7gq7uk2y4kjygzipmzztamxq7zbhw4m47iyfrvleknv4axfhhxudjs5nyx5ijd27q5aqjjg6bqac2wheaznk2ouqhjumdro5dntkvduvzupds7a3psdwsefgy5eeijwasj3vzh2p&lastPosition=100

https://www.imdb.com/user/ur3954564/ratings?sort=date_added%2Cdesc&mode=detail&paginationKey=mfq5ijak6z7uymjwuuwsomnsegl34knnqsdztp6xeepepyyfxdfiwpol52uhtjimq3iwclnm7gq7uk2y4kjygzaenj3tooxr7vch65447iyfrvleknv4axfhhxudjs5nyx6ifb24rrhqjjg6bqac2wheaznk2ouqhjumdro5dntkvduvzupds7enxphz4xkrobzbcb4wvm7y7dnp&lastPosition=200
```

Comment: So need ratings given by `DaveHedgehog`. IMDb says there are 10,024  results. But if you see this https://www.imdb.com/user/ur3954564/ratings?sort=date_added%2Cdesc&mode=detail&paginationKey=mfq5ijak6z7uymjwuuwsomnsegl34knnqsdztp6xeepepyyfxdfiwpol52uhtjimq3iwclnm7gq7uk2y4kjygzynnj7din7s7ndho4m47iyfrvleknv4axfhhxudjs5nyx5ipb27qnhb564pajlxuqffl4f7yiuinvqy5t6rdjt2tdedsipdslvlyjd6ryhikvvhyqrpopmgk6q&lastPosition=11000 it shows upto 11000 results.

Comment: Have you looked into [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf)? I think you can use it without it opening a browser (so [headless browsing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/headless.html) )